# Чи є плеоназмом словосполучення інтернет-сайт?

Tags: вживання-слів

Згідно з [Вікіпедією](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC),

> Плеона́зм (від грец. πλεονασμός — надлишок, надмірність) —
>   надлишковість засобів, що використовуються для передачі лексичного чи
>   граматичного змісту висловлювання. Плеоназм як властивість тексту є
>   протилежністю еліпсису і виявляє себе у повторенні чи синонімічному
>   дублюванні лексем (лексичний плеоназм) або граматичних форм
>   (граматичний плеоназм), а також у надто багатослівній передачі змісту,
>   який може бути висловлено коротше.

Зрозуміло, що вираз "смертельно вбитий труп загиблого мерця" - мовна помилка. А як бути з відносно новими утвореннями?

Новітній онлайновий словник української мови (2013—2018) надає таке тлумачення слова сайт:

> **сайт**, -у, чол. Те саме, що веб-сайт.
>
> **веб-са́йт**, -у, чол. Сукупність взаємопов'язаних посиланнями та змістом
>   веб-сторінок, опублікованих та підтримуваних певною особою, групою
>   осіб чи організацією з метою поширення чи обміну інформацією; сайт.

Якщо врахувати, що Веб (англ. web , «павутина») — інтернет-простір, то вислів *інтернет-сайт* видається плеоназмом. Тим не менш, на таку сполуку можемо натрапити в інтернет-виданнях.
Чи відноситься сполучення *інтернет-сайт* до негативних мовних явищ, чи стало унормованим, як, наприклад, експонат виставки?

Comment: А «веб-сайт» Ви теж розглядаєте як кандидат в плеоназми  (чи лише «інтернет-сайт»)?

Comment: @Sasha, як на мене, розглядала би, тому що назва сайт, на відміну від англійської, в українській мові може стосуватися лише інтернет-простору. Але (на жаль) слово "веб-сайт" є у словнику))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Про запозичення зі звуженим значенням

Будь-яка мова має запозичення. Але часто трапляється, що запозичене слово має значно вужчий спектр значень, ніж воно мало в тій мові, звідки воно взято (або навіть якесь доволі специфічне значення, непритаманне мові-джерелу). Наприклад, [анонс](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=1252&page=53) — попереднє/завчасне оголошення про щось (у той час як у французькій це просто повідомлення про щось, не обов'язково попереднє), [репарація](http://sum.in.ua/s/reparacija) — відшкодування збитків, завданих державі, що перемогла у війні, за рахунок переможеної держави, яка розв'язала війну (а латиною reparatio — це будь-яке відновлення, без військової специфіки) тощо. Чому так трапляється — по-моєму очевидно: мова, що запозичує слово, вже може мати слова/вирази для загального вжитку, а от для якогось конкретного підзначення — ще не мати.

Однак, якщо якесь слово запозичене зі звуженим значенням, я не впевнений, що використання при ньому додаткових слів — аналогічних тим, що були потрібні у мові-донорі через широке значення слова-оригінала там (але теоретично непотрібні у мові-акцепторі через вузьке значення тут) — можна вважати дійсними плеоназмами. Звісно, чим далі мови віддаляються одна від одної і чим більш втрачає запозичене слово зв'язок зі словом-оригіналом, тим недоречніше можуть виглядати такі уточнення — але на початковому етапі, коли слово тільки-но засвоєне мовою, використання в ній сполук, притаманних мові-оригіналу, по-моєму, доволі природнє. Навіть при давно запозичених словах ми іноді зберігаємо (вже начебто непотрібні) уточнення, наприклад, «військова репарація», «церковна інквізиція» тощо.

Англійською site — це вього навсього місце/місцеположення/локація (не обов'язково в Інтернеті, а в Інтернеті, у фізичному світі (в місті, на природі тощо) тощо). Хоча й англійською web- і internet- перед словом -site можуть опускаюти, але там ці уточнення доволі значимі. Не дивно, що їх автоматично вживають і в українській  мові.

## Про неточність означень у словнику

Також, оскільки слово «сайт» доволі нове в українській мові, не слід розраховувати, що його означення в тлумачних словниках будуть на 100 відсотків точними.

Фактично, хоч словники можуть це наразі не зазначати, але сторінка і сайт (сайт — це певна сукупність сторінок) можуть бути не лише в Інтернеті. Зокрема сторінка і сайт можуть бути доступними лише в локальній мережі. Наприклад, деякі організації мають внутрішні сайти для службового користування, але з метою недопущення витоку інформації ці сайти можуть бути недоступними ззовні (а робоча мережа може бути взагалі непід'єднаною до Інтернету). Тобто буває «інтернет-сайт» (сайт, доступний із майже будь-якого місця світу) і «інтранет-сайт» (сайт, доступний лише в локальній мережі).

Щодо частинки веб-, то через вищезгадане явище можливого звуження/корегування значення в запозиченнях, я не можу точно сказати, чи має насправді ця частинка якусь (можливо, малозрозумілу широкому загалу, але значиму в професійних колах) роль у слові «веб-сайт» чи ні. Бо я не знаю, еквівалентом якого, власне, англійського вислову є українське «веб»: або це просто «web» (тобто павутиння), або це саме «worldwide web» (тобто всесвітнє павутиння). У другому випадку буде, мабуть, те саме, що й з частнкою «інтернет-» — сайти зможуть бути «веб-» і «не веб-»; у першому ж, здається, «веб-сайт» і «сайт» будуть точнісінько одним і тим самим. (Однак навіть у цьому випадку я не впевнений, що «веб-сайт» можна назвати плеоназмом. Фактично все вирішиться практикою у майбутньому: (1) або слово «сайт» настільки відірветься від англійського «site», що частинка «веб-» стане йому абсолютно непотрібною і навіть вважатиметься помилкою; (2) або слово «сайт» розширить своє значення (якщо не до рівня англійського «site», то хоч принаймні стане ширшим за «веб-сайт»); (3) або залишиться статус-кво (ані формальне обґрунтування ролі частинки «веб-» не з'явиться, ані вплив англійської мови не зникне.)