# Site, сайт чи все ж ділянка?

Tags: переклад, from-english

Можливо це не те місце, де можна писати про такі речі, але це єдине з відомих мені місць де допомагають на подібні теми.

Отож, **site, або сайт**. Цікаве слово, яке вже намертво прижилося в нашій мові і претендує на закріплення у словнику. Але чи правильно це?

Я вважаю, що ця претензія на місце у словнику є хибною і помилкою (або якщо хочете: відсутністю достатніх знань, некомпетентність. Про що переконуюся щодня все більше) тих людей, які займаються перекладом цих комп'ютерних термінів.

Подібне використання говіркових слів погіршує розуміння того, що відбувається насправді в подіях, які ці слова описують. Приховує. Приховує через нерозуміння чи погане розуміння іноземних слів.

Мене цікавить ваша думка щодо цього.

Поясню свою точку зору. Якщо прочитати значення слова site в англійському довіднику, то це:

> A site is a piece of ground that is used for a particular purpose or
>   where a particular thing happens.
>
> The site of an important event is the place where it happened.
>
> A site is a piece of ground where something such as a statue or
>   building stands or used to stand.

[Джерело](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/web)

По суті своїй означає "ділянка".

За своєю логікою це слово збігається за значенням введеного слова "сайт", а точніше web site, а ще точніше "ділянка павутини". І тут все збіглося до купи. Усе зрослося в голові. Усе прояснилося. Це той момент, коли розумієш: "Чому раніше про це не подумав?". Тобто якби одразу перекладали усе правильно, то і літературу читати було б легше. І простіше пояснювати.

Уявіть павутину дротів, в якій є купа точок з'єднань. (Ну взагалі, зможете знайти зображення павутини в інтернеті.) І на цій павутині є ділянки, в яких є певна інформація для читання. Ділянки мають свої адреси. Ділянкам можна змінювати адреси. Для доступу до ділянок використовуються служби, які забезпечують передачу даних для читання у правильному вигляді (протоколі).

Суть запитання у тому, чи правий я чи ні у тому, що: **web site - це ділянка павутини**? Тобто в даному випадку можна використати прямий переклад.

На вільну тему: Чи вже настав той час, коли запізно донести правильно думку про переклад слова?

Ознайомився з цією [відповіддю](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/3713/%D0%A7%D0%B8-%D1%94-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82). Тобто в даному випадку інтернет-сайт - це  ділянка міжмережжя (це точніше описує речі та зв'язки і відповідає англійському словосполученню internet site). Просто як по маслу.

Також підтверджується моє бачення перекладу в [цій](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/297984/site-vs-website) відповіді.

> so saying I visited their site could mislead the hearer to think I had
>   visited a physical location rather than an electronic one

*Отже, коли кажу я відвідав їх site (ділянку), то це може ввести в оману слухача, бо вважається як я відвідав фізичне місце, а не електронне.*

Comment: Я б уже тоді особисто пропонував не ділянку, а _місцину_. Але, якщо чесно, я не думаю, що це має сенс. Це нормально, коли в мові є власне слово з широким значенням, але для якогось вузького використовується запозичення (яке в мові-оригіналі мало широке значення); наприклад, виконання і екзекуція; місце і локус; образ і гештальт. Як на мене, це радше англійці страждають через те, що в них немає точного й короткого слова для поняття «сайт» (а використовується загальне, яке насправді багатозначне, але нічого вже не зміниш). Але це лише моя думка.

Comment: Відносно вживаним також є _осїдок_.

Comment: «Хорошилище грядет из ристалища на позорище по гульбищу в мокроступах и с растопыркой» ось це хочеться цитувати коли технічні терміни починають намагатися замінити на нативні слова.

Comment: @AntonKukoba, чи ви намагалися звернутися до якогось іншого, окрім російського, досвіду? Я гадки не маю, чи буде зиск від цього конкретного обговорення, але нативізація термінів - дуже поширена практика в багатьох мовах (німецька, французька, чеська, іврит тощо), і вона не заважає розумінню дисциплін носіями мови.

Comment: @AndriyIvanchenko проблема не в тому, що щось доводить щось інше або ні. Словотвір не працює за принципом "правильності" перекладу, він працює за дуже багатьма факторами, якими не можна нехтувати. Ви кажете: "це говірка, яку треба викореніти, доки не пізно", але на чому базується ваше переконання? Ви мовознавець?

Comment: @P.Vowk Мої переконання базуються на досвіді, на тому що я прочитав та чого мене вчили. Ніхто тут досі не зміг спростувати мої переконань. І чим більше я вивчаю англійську мову та поглиблюю знання української - тим більше я переконую себе у своїх знаннях. Сьогодні мода на активне використання англійських слів і забуття українських і це дуже сумно. Сумно, що мода на іноземне переважає моду на знання.

Comment: @Andriy Ivanchenko мені теж трохи сумно від частини того, що ви перелічуєте, але, на жаль, це мовознавчий сайт, а ви не хочете розбиратися в мовознавстві.

Answer (score 6):

### ← Зерна — Полова →

Маємо три варіанти: site, сайт, ділянка. Одразу доведеться розрізнити пару речей:

1. Слова site в українській мові бути не може. Українська мова кирилічна.
2. *Станом на сьогодні* жодне зі [значень](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/?page=773&searchWord=%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0&wordid=22692) слова ділянка не пасує на [означення](http://sum.in.ua/f/veb-sajt) "сукупності взаємопов'язаних посиланнями та змістом веб-сторінок, опублікованих та підтримуваних певною особою, групою осіб чи організацією з метою поширення чи обміну інформацією".
3. Найновіший СУМ у 20-ти томах на позначення такої сукупності [фіксує](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/?wordid=182272&page=264&searchWord=%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1#lid_182272) слова: **сайт; веб-сайт**. Отже *станом на сьогодні* лиш ці два слова надаються до позначення такої сукупності.
4. Отже слово "сайт" не "претендує на місце у словнику", воно його там вже займає, це найновіша норма української мови.

### До компетентності укладачів словників

Зворотнє питання: чим вимірюється компетентність? Дозволю собі нахабність і скажу, що вона вимірюється орієнтуванням тих, хто перекладає, у способах запозичення слів з іншої мови та їхнього перекладу.

Сходімо за цим [посиланням](http://www.macmillandictionaries.com/MED-Magazine/March2006/36-New-Word-Neologisms.htm) і подивимось на те, як можуть запозичуватися слова з анґлійської в інші мови. Виділимо такі способи:

1. Транслітерація - механічна передача тексту й окремих слів, які записані однією графічною системою, засобами іншої графічної системи при другорядній ролі звукової точності, тобто передача однієї писемності літерами іншої.
2. Адаптація форми, але зміна змісту (слово залишається те саме, але його смисл у мові-реципієнті змінюється). Адаптація - передача слова із змінами, наприклад, морфолоґічними.
3. Повна адаптація форми і змісту.
4. Пошук відповідників у мові-реципієнті (це той варіант, який найбільше цікавить вас, до міжнародної практики такого пошуку я повернуся наприкінці відповіді).

Бачимо, що запозичення іноземних слів через транслітерацію і адаптацію, а не через пошук відповідника, відбувається й переважає у багатьох мовах. Отже не можемо стверджувати нічого про компетентність фахівців, що запозичують іноземні слова через транслітерацію і адаптацію.

"Подібне використання говіркових слів погіршує розуміння того, що відбувається насправді в подіях, які ці слова описують. Приховує. Приховує через нерозуміння чи погане розуміння іноземних слів." - це лише ваша думка. Я також вважаю, що треба знаходити відповідники до іноземних слів там, де це не виглядає як мовне насильство, але це лиш моя думка і я не кажу, що хтось, хто її не дотримується, некомпетентний, адже світова практика показує розмаїття способів запозичення, і той, що цікавить вас, у ній не переважає.

### Чи можна використати прямий переклад?

Коротко: можна, але не завжди.

Трішки довше: 1. Якщо ви хочете, щоби вас зрозуміло якомога ширше коло людей, вам доведеться перекласти через усталений варіант. 2. Якщо це професійний переклад, вам також доведеться використати усталений варіант, щоби потім змігти послатися на словник, якщо виникнуть питання. Але ви завжди можете ризикнути ;) 3. Якщо це просто неформальне спілкування і ви хочете просувати свій варіант у маси - не бачу жодних перешкод. У крайньому разі вас попросять уточнити, що ви маєте на увазі.

### Чи вже запізно доносити правильну думку про переклад слова?

Щодо правильності думки я вже писав вище. Я дуже сумніваюся, що вашу думку можна назвати "правильною". Вона безперечно дуже цікава, але "правильність" - це суб'єктивне поняття.

Коротко про "запізно": ні, не "запізно". Якщо ви досі глибоко переконаний у своїй правоті (а я сподіваюся, що мені вдалося трохи підважити вашу переконаність), ви завжди можете спробувати ввести український відповідник у якомога ширший вжиток, а через 50-100 років люди в українських корпусах дослідять, чи він прижився. Ми ніколи не знаємо, як станеться з мовою, мовні передбачення - це досі недосліджена царина.

Від себе скажу, що ваша візія того, як побудований інтернет, яскрава, і досить добре доводить, що один сайт - це ділянка, але, на жаль, цього недостатньо. Для введення того чи іншого слова до вжитку потрібний консенсус якоїсь частини суспільства і підхоплення новотвору помітною частиною спільноти, що користується мовою-реципієнтом.

### Складнощі творення українських відповідників замість запозичень

Є декілька мов, у яких кількість новотворів-відповідників, що використовуються замість прямих запозичень, набагато більша, аніж у решті мов. До таких мов належать **іврит** і **чеська**.

У Ізраїлі працює Академія мови іврит, далі цитата з їхнього [сайту](https://en.hebrew-academy.org.il/mission-and-vision/):

> Here, as one would expect, **new Hebrew words and terms are created**, and standards are set for grammar, orthography, transliteration and punctuation.

Перше, чим займається ця академія, — створення нових слів і понять. Отже це ціла інституція, де працює [декілька десятків](https://en.hebrew-academy.org.il/about-the-academy/the-structure-of-the-academy/) професіоналів, що дуже добре знаються на мові іврит, а також багато позаштатних працівників-помічників.

У Чехії я поки не знайшов інституції, яка би займалася цим напряму. Це дає надію, що такий активний процес словотвору можливий без інституційної підтримки, але тут треба проводити додаткове дослідження. З іншого боку, суперечки про вплив німецької на чеську йдуть, а доцільність новотворів у Чехії [обговорюється](https://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josef_Dobrovsk%C3%BD#cite_ref-67) ще з кінця 18 століття, ось уривок статті на вікі про чеського славіста і (здається) першого слов'янського філолога:

> Ve sporu s Pohlem se mladý Dobrovský vzepřel jeho puristickému novotaření ve slovotvorbě a upevnil při tom svou argumentaci o výhodnosti kontinuity se starým bratrským pravopisem. Zlobického pak kritizoval za jeho germanizující právnickou češtinu v překladech říšských zákoníků.

Мій довільний переклад:

> У суперечці з Полем (ще один лінґвіст - прим. пер.) ще юний Добровський висловлювався проти його пуристичного словотвору, підтверджуючи свою позицію арґументом про зручність нерозривності зі старим братським правописом. Злобицького критикував за ґерманізацію правничої чеської у перекладах імперських законів.

Отже Чехія має досить довгу традицію словотвору, що починається ще у 18-му столітті, чим ми похвастатися не можемо, але можемо прямувати до подовження й укріплення [нашої традиції](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%96_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0), що бере початок від Старицького, Лесі Українки тощо (середина - кін. 19 ст) і продовжується на сайті [словотвір](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/sait), де **ділянка** станом на сьогодні - не найпопулярніший відповідник слова "сайт". Але все залежить від вашої затятості й самовпевненості, якщо вони протривають достатньо довго, можливо, вам усе вдасться.

### Фердінан де Сосюр

Це засновник сучасної лінґвістики, яка розрослася, самозаперечилася і знову утвердилася. Він ввів такі поняття як "означник" (фр. signifiant, англ. signifier) і "означуване" (фр. signifié, англ. signified). Перше (означник) - слово, яке ми використовуємо, щоби означити для того, хто слухає/читає, друге (означуване). Ф. де Сосюр висловлювався за те, що зв'язок між означником і означуваним довільний, випадковий, і залежить від всієї матриці кожної окремої мови.

Про це можна почитати тут: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_(semiotics)

Його теза досі користується популярністю і я не чув про якесь задовільне заперечення цієї тези. Висновок з неї такий, що слово "сайт" цілком може бути довільним означником того, що ви називаєте "ділянкою павутини", і ви не можете насильно цьому зарадити. Ви можете запропонувати спільноті, що має до діла з українською мовою, свій варіант, але його введення у вжиток буде справою випадку.

Comment: Ги, СУМ-20 вже застарів (якшчо не оновювати ймуть) — за [правописом 2019](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/05062019-onovl-pravo.pdf#page=34) вже _вебсайт_, без дефісу.

Comment: @stegetsj думаю, вони оновлять словники НАН і перейдуть до цього. Загалом вебсайт докорінно нічого не змінює, але так, смішно)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101836/discussion-between-p-vowk-and-andriy-ivanchenko).

Comment: @AndriyIvanchenko Google-перекладач https://translate.google.com на 97% якісно робить переклад слів на будь-яку мову світу. Тобто він кращий за 97 зі 100 професійних перекладачів-мовознавців.

Comment: @RomanMikhol ви хто за освітою?

Comment: @P. Vowk Економічна статистика - моя спеціальність, але понад п'ять років брав участь в удосконаленні перекладача Google і вже більше року ця програма закрита, бо гугл-транслейтор не робить помилок.

Comment: @Roman Mikhol ви розумієте різницю між перекладом слів і речень, абзаців, контекстів?

Comment: @P. Vowk з дев'ятого по одинадцятий клас робив російсько-український переклад статей від п'яти тисяч слів двічі на тиждень зі словником. А чому у вас виникло таке питання?